# Как уменьшать высоту формы сверху вниз

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, c++-cli

Хочу сделать всплывающие окна с эффектом плавного появления и исчезновения.
Эффект хочу сделать такой:

1. this->Height = 0
2. По таймеру начинает изменяться this->height пока не станет к примеру 100
3. В таком состоянии форма находится ~2 сек
4. this->height по таймеру начинает изменяться от 100 до нуля таким образом чтобы форма, какбы сворачивалась начиная с верха.
5. this->Close();

Первые 2 пункта не сложно и я написал такой класс:

```
void Opac1ty::height_add(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
send_forma->Opacity = 0.97;
if (send_forma->Height < height){
    send_forma->Height = send_forma->Height + i;
    //MessageBox::Show("+i");
}
else send_forma->Height = height;
i++;
}

void Opac1ty::set(Form^ form){
send_forma = form;
height = form->Height;
i = 0;
timer = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer;
timer->Interval = 8;
form->Height = 0;
timer->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Opac1ty::height_add);
timer->Start();
}
```

А вот изменение высоты формы с верху вниз меня застопорило так что даже идей никаких нет. Потому что высота и ширина формы вычисляется от верхнего левого угла (на сколько я знаю). Или может быть можно как то изменить место этого отсчета да еще и в процессе работы формы?

Comment: вы хотите чтобы форма плавно исчезала? или уменьшалась?можно сделать и то и другое, но естественно по разному

Comment: я же описал всё. Плавное уменьшение начиная сверху

Comment: Тогда не вижу проблемы менять одновременно высоту и положение верхнего левого угла. Смотрите свойство `Form.Location`, его можно свободно менять во время работы.